# Create a dataframe which shows the Relationship between 2 Dataframes

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, relational-database

Hello this is my first Question and I tried everything.

I'm new to Dataframe and SQL and I have an excel table with multiple Movies. It has the Columns Movie Name, Year ,...,and Actors.
In the Column Actors are multiple Actors listet, which are separated by , or by /.
I created a Dataframe Movies which have a UUID, and all the information I should store for a Movie. I also filtered all Actors which are in all my Movies and created a DataFrame called Actors with also a Unique ID and Name and stored them individually.

DF_MOVIE:

| Movie ID | Actors |
| --- | --- |
| x | Person1,Person2,Person5 |
| y | Person1 |

DF_ACTORS:

| ActorID | Actor |
| --- | --- |
| a | Person1 |
| b | Person 5 |

What I want to create is a new Dataframe which shows the Relationship between them.

For Example:

DF_ACTORS_MOVIE:

| MOVIEID | ACTORID |
| --- | --- |
| x | a |
| x | b |

The Problem is: there Actors in my Excel table (and Bookdf). And I want to take both IDS.

Does anybody have an Idea?
would appreciate, Thanks..:

I tried iterating both the Dataframe books and tried to create a new Entry on the DF_ACTORS_MOVIE Dataframe with both UUIDS. The Problem is, that there are multiple Actors and they are divided by , and by /.

Comment: Don't you also want to map movie y for actor a?

Comment: Yes it just was an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `explode` the Actors into a new column:

```
out = df_actors.merge(df_movie.assign(Actor=df_movie['Actors'].str.split(','))
                                            .explode('Actor').drop(columns='Actors')
                      )
```

Output:

```
  ActorID    Actor Movie ID
0       a  Person1        x
1       a  Person1        y
2       b  Person5        x
```

Comment: It shows me this error: pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: Which pandas version do you have? This work fine in the lastest release. Ensure `df_actors` has an "Actor" column